# ionic 4: i got errror during using (ionChange) Select-Option to display students who selected specific subject

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

i am trying to show students who selected specific subject after selecting subject in select-option , when i use `(ionChange)=viewStudents(subject.subid,subject.name)`i got error this error: ***Cannot read property 'subid' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (MarksViewPage.html:127)***
actually when i use `viewStudents(subject.subid,subject.name)` on (click) in other method its work.

please help me to solve this error

html:

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selected" (ionChange)="viewStudents(subject.subid,subject.name)">
     <ion-select-option *ngFor="let subject of choosedSubjects_viewMarks;let i=index" 
     [value]="subject.subid">{{subject.name}}</ion-select-option> 
    </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

.ts file:

```
    async viewStudents(sub_id,sub_name) {
         this.SujectID = sub_id;
         this.title = sub_name;
         this.enable_subjects = false; 
         **this.enable_students = true;**
         this.searchlistResult = false;
         this.ionViewDidEnter() ;
            }
```

when i disable other lists this list will display:

```
  async viewMarks(studentid,input) {

        console.log(studentid, this.teach_id, this.SujectID, input);

        return new Promise(resolve => {
          let body = {
          aksi: 'add_marks',
          sid:   studentid,
          tid:   this.teach_id,
          subID: this.SujectID,
          marks: input
        }
        this.accessProvds.postData(body,'proses_api.php').subscribe((res: any) => {
          if (res.success == true) {
            this.presentToast('Added successfuly!');
            this.ionViewDidEnter();

          } else {
            this.presentToast(res.msg);
          }
        });


      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `subject` is defined as an iterator of ngFor directive. However, your `ionChange` is defined outside. Thus it does not know what is subject.

In order to make your code working your template should look as follows:

```
<ion-item>
     <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selected"
                 (ionChange)="viewStudents(selected.subid,selected.name)">
     <ion-select-option *ngFor="let subject of choosedSubjects_viewMarks; let i=index" 
     [value]="subject">{{subject.name}}</ion-select-option> 
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Please note two important points:

1. I'm passing the whole `subject` object as option value
2. I'm passing to `viewStudents` the `selected` object as long as it is defined in `ngModel`

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and correct answer **Sergey Mell**

Comment: You're welcome! Actually the question is not about Ionic but about Angular bindings.

Comment: sure , for that added angular as a tag